# The page number in a table of content is not aligned

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex

I am working on my PhD thesis and trying to align the numbers in the table of content [image: currently is looking like this.]. 
I can see these lines in the content.tex, but as you can see numbers are not aligned. Build with pdflatex, texmaker and bibtext

```
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % <-- 2 includes up to subsections in the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <-- 3 numbers up to subsubsections
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsc{\thesection}\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
```

Comment: That's a precise choice of the `classicthesis` format you seem to be using. Add the `tocaligned` option to `\usepackage{classicthesis}`.

Comment: @egreg I added the option but did not change the result.

Comment: @AH2012: ...then provide more detail/context so we can replicate this behaviour. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: @AH2012 Then try adding also `dottedtoc`

Comment: @egreg Thank you. It works.